# How to train 3 models with single loss function in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

```
optimizer=torch.optim.AdamW(list(model3.parameters())+list(model1.parameters())+list(model2.parameters())) 

optimizer.zero_grad()

prediction=model3(model1(x)+model2(x))

loss=nn.BCELoss(prediction,labels)

loss.backward()

optimizer.step()
```

[image]

How can I update parameters of all three models with single loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no problem with the code you showed. The gradients are propagated all the way up, unless you do something to prevent it (e.g. `.detach()`, `param.requires_grad = False`, etc)

Comment: How parameters of the models are updated. in what sequence parameters of the models are updated

Comment: When you compute the forward pass, the information about which operations have been performed is stored. When you invoke `loss.backward()`, the gradients are computed (back-propagation) using the stored operations information; these gradients are then saved in each parameter's `.grad` attribute. When you invoke `optimizer.step()`, the parameters registered in the optimizer are updated; the order in which they are updated is irrelevant, because the gradients have already been computed, from the loss node up to the beginning of the operations chain.